# Get Image from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get an image from a subarray, of an array and display the correct size. I have managed to store the subarray into a variable but cannot seem to grab the image.
I would like to output the [media_url] and [thumb] size.

Here is the array output via print_r():

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 81223091856078976
            [id_str] => 81223091856078976
            [indices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 23
                )

            [media_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/media/C0Wft4WEAACVt_.jpg
            [media_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C0Wft4WEAACVt_.jpg
            [url] => https://xxxxxxx.com
            [display_url] => pic.twitter.com/xxxxxxx
            [expanded_url] => https://twitter.com/xxxxxxx/status/8122309393021504/photo/1
            [type] => photo
            [sizes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [medium] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [w] => 1108
                            [h] => 784
                            [resize] => fit
                        )

                    [thumb] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [w] => 150
                            [h] => 150
                            [resize] => crop
                        )

                    [small] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [w] => 680
                            [h] => 481
                            [resize] => fit
                        )

                    [large] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [w] => 1108
                            [h] => 784
                            [resize] => fit
                        )

                )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$arr[0]->media_url` and `$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->w` and `$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->h` and `$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->resize`

Comment: looks like your array contains objects. object methods and properties are accessed via the -> operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$arr[0]->media_url
$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->w
$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->h
$arr[0]->sizes->thumb->resize
```

Note:- if you are using `foreach()` then remove `[0]` from all.